# php redirect the stdout as soon as it is generated

Tags: php, python, stdout

Inside a php script a call the function shell_exec to execute a python script and redirect the stdout to a file. This a piece of my code:

```
shell_exec("pythonScript > progress.txt");
```

The python script write on stdout a new line every five second. Everything is successful but the output of python script is write on file only at the end of its execution and not every five second. I tried also with this code:

```
shell_exec("pythonScript > progress.txt &");
```

but i have the same effect. 
How should I do to make sure that the stdout is written to file direttament when it is generated?

Comment: This most likely has nothing to do with PHP, but with the python script not flushing its output.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson but if i execute the python script by command line the output is regularly printed every five seconds

Comment: shell_exec doesn't return until the command finishes. Your PHP is just waiting for that to finish.

Comment: @moopet i also use the '&' at the and of command to execute the python script in backgound, but i have the same result

Comment: Output buffering doesn't normally happen when output is going to a terminal, but it does when output is to a file (because files aren't as impatient as humans).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is most likely due to buffering in your python script. To turn off `stdout` buffering in the python script, either;

- Use `sys.stdout.flush()` every time you want to be sure that the output so far is sent to the file.
- Start python with the option `-u` which disables `stdout` buffering. In your case it should probably be done inside the script, replacing the first line;

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

(or similar, depending on the path) with

```
#!/usr/bin/python -u
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are using the redirect operator `>` which will *overwrite* the output file everytime it runs, which is why you only see one line (the last line of the command's output). You need to use `>>` to append to the file:

```
$ echo 'foo' > out.txt
$ echo 'bar' > out.txt
$ cat out.txt
bar
$ echo 'foo' >> out.txt
$ echo 'bar' >> out.txt
$ cat out.txt
bar
foo
bar
```